# react context lost after stripe returns to success page

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, react-context

My app uses NextJs 13 using pages
I am using react context holding basket info.
After I make a call to Stripe checkout, I get a redirect from Stripe to my payment success page. In the success page my context information is now empty.
How get the context information back.

I call stripe with

```
const checkoutSession: Stripe.Checkout.Session =
            await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
```

My context covers the whole app.

```
<UserProvider>
            <LayoutProvider>
                <BasketProvider>
                    <Layout>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </Layout>
                </BasketProvider>
            </LayoutProvider>
        </UserProvider>
```

How do I retrieve the BasketProvider data in the stripe success page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. The approach I took was:

1. Save the context values to DB and save the ID as metadata item in the stripe call;
2. In the pages/api directory listen for webhook event checkout.session.completed and then get the context id from DB so I can recreate the context object.

Answer (score 0):

Your context is empty because you leave the page when redirecting to stripe. There are two options how this can be tackled:

1. There is probably some parameters that are passed by stripe back to your page that will allow you to fetch the data again in the success page.
2. You can persist your data in some form or shape and rehydrate your context with it when the success page is rendered.

Comment: Thanks I will use Redis in serverless api to store the context and retrieve the context after I return from stripe.